# drop dataframes that don't match condition R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I have a list of 310 data.frames, `mrns[[i]]`, that I am subsetting based on the value of a factor, `mrns[[i]]$ar.cat`. I am able to use subset on them all in a way that those data.frames that don't match the condition are left with 0 observations, but I would like the code to just remove these data.frames rather than leave them in the new list as empty.

My code is:

```
arlow <- lapply(mrns, function(x) subset(x, x$ar.cat[1] == "Arousals Index: LOW"))
```

Which gives me:

```
length(arlow)
[1] 310
```

When I see the contents of the `arlow` list, I see this for the data.frames that don't meet the condition:

```
[[98]]
[1] raw.Number         raw.Reading_Status raw.Month          raw.Day            raw.Year          
[6] raw.Hour           raw.Minute         raw.Systolic       raw.Diastolic      raw.MAP           
[11] raw.PP             raw.HR             raw.Event_Code     raw.Edit_Status    raw.Diary_Activity
[16] na.strings         raw.facility       raw.lastname       raw.firstname      raw.id            
[21] raw.hookup         raw.datetime       raw.mrn            unis               ar.value          
[26] ar.cat             ID                 avg.hr.prhr        avg.sys.prhr       avg.dias.prhr     
[31] avg.map.prhr       avg.pp.prhr        time               time_60            raw.Minutee       
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Let's say that the `x$ar.cat[1] == "Arousals Index: LOW"` condition is only met in 180 of my 310 `mrns[[i]]` data.frames, I would want the result of `length(arlow)` to equal 180.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to remove those data.frames not matching the condition?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using R 3.2.0+ you can try `arlow[lengths(arlow) > 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your responses! I found the added the following code and gave me what I was looking for.

```
> arlow <- arlow[sapply(arlow, function(x) dim(x)[1]) > 0]
> length(arlow)
[1] 103
```

Answer (score 2):

How about that

```
arlow <- lapply( lapply(mrns, function(x) subset(x, x$ar.cat[1] == "Arousals Index: LOW")), function(y) nrow(y) >0)
```

first you filter that you did and then take frames only with data.

Comment: Ah, good call @Szymon! When I run that, I get a list of true false values as my arlow list. `> arlow[[1]] = [1] FALSE` It's close, I just need to figure out how to get rid of those dataframes that come back false.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to remove the `NULL`s from `arlow`?

Try:

```
arlow <- arlow[[!is.null(arlow)]]
```

As in:

```
lst <- list(data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10)), NULL, data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10)))
length(lst)
# [1] 3

result <- lst[[!is.null(lst)]]
length(result)
# [1] 2
```

Here's [another way](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-rid-of-NULL-in-the-result-of-apply-td960776.html):

```
result <- Filter(Negate(is.null), lst)
length(result)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward! That gives me a length of 35 for some reason, and I know that I have more than 35 empty dataframes. I ended up using `dim` above and it gave me what I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Length is the number of non-empty data.frames.

Answer (score 1):

edit: Actually, my answer does not make much sense. I did not do the subsetting in each data frame that you want. I still think which() is useful to subset without NA and NULL values, though.

```
mrns[which(sapply(1:length(mrns), function(x) mrns[x]$ar.cat == "Arousals Index: LOW"))]
```

This solution tests if the category (ar.cat) has the answer "Arousals Index: LOW" for each data frame in your list of data frames. The resulting vector should have 320 elements, where elements that met the condition are true.
Now we use which() to get the indices of the true values. These indices should ignore any NULL or NA values that occur in the vector we produced.
As a last step we subset the list of data frames with the indices we want.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Thanks @CarlAH. I ran the code and got `Error in which(sapply(1:length(mrns), function(x) mrns[x]$ar.cat == "Arousals Index: LOW")) : argument to 'which' is not logical`. I found what I needed but it's nice to see different ways of doing things.